# why Route::currentRouteName() not working in laravel 5 inside a controller method

Tags: regex, laravel, routes

why  Route::currentRouteName() not working in laravel 5 inside a controller method , but when i provide '\' before class name works . I need to know the reason why adding back slash before class works in this scenario. May be it is some oops scenerio , which i don't know . Please guide

$name = \Route::currentRouteName();

Comment: You should read up about Namespaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand  how PHP Namespaces works.

`Route` is not within the controller namespace hence you need to provide the full namespace to `Route` class for it to be loaded. `Route` is in root namespace hence you reference it with `\Route` just like you would do in directory structures.

Assuming your controller looks like this:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controller
class HomeController extends Controller{

   public function index(){
      //Doing this will throw a Not Found exception because route is 
      //not inside `App\Http\Controller` namespace
      $name = Route::currentRouteName(); 

      //However if you specify the correct namespace it works like so:
      $name = \Route::currentRouteName(); 
   }

}
```

You can read more about namespace here:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Comment: Ok thanks for yout suggestion @Digitlimit , but in this syntax \Route::currentRouteName();  if \ has been used since its in root namspace , but why then they they have given in their doc omiting slash . And Route is in root  namespace then don't we need to include its namespace using "use" keyword. Can you please explain a bit. I m novice to this , so i need some guide

Comment: If you are using Route in routes.php you don't need \

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
\Request::route()->getName()
```

or

```
\Route::getCurrentRoute()->getPath();
```

Comment: This does not answer the question which is why is the \ required, they are already aware that it only seems to work when they use it.